# How to use VTK to efficiently write time-varying field data on a fixed mesh?

Tags: visualization, simulation, vtk, paraview

I am working on physics simulation research. I have a large fixed grid in one of my projects that does not vary with time. The fields on the grid, on the other hand, vary with time in the simulation. I need to use VTK to record the field data in each step for visualization (Paraview).

The method I am using is to write a separate `*.vtu` file to disk at each time step. This basically serves the purpose, but actually writes a lot of duplicate data (re-recording the geometry of the mesh at each step), which not only consumes more disk space, but also wastes time on encoding and parsing.

I would like to have a way to write the mesh information only once, and the rest of the time only new field data is written, while being able to guarantee the same visualization. Please let me know if VTK and Paraview provide such an interface and how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `.pvtu` and refer to the same `.vtu` as `Piece` for each step should do the trick.

See this [similar post](https://discourse.paraview.org/t/vtk-separate-mesh-and-data-files/10134) on the ParaView discourse, and the [pvtu doc](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/VTKFileFormats/#punstructuredgrid)

**EDIT**
This seems to be a side effect of the format, this is not supported by the writer.
The correct solution is to use another file format ...

Comment: My understanding is that you are proposing to use a vtu file to hold all the geometry point information, another file to hold the field data at a particular moment, and then a pvtu file to link these files together.

However, I looked up the documentation and tutorials for the vtk library and didn’t find any relevant examples. The relevant functions of the vtkXMLPUnstructuredGridWriter class do not look like the functionality I want. Can you provide a simple example to show me how to do this?

Comment: You are right concerning my proposition, but sadly you are also rigth about the missing feature in the writer ... My suggestion seems to be a side effect no really supported ...

Comment: Disappointing news indeed. I've posted my conclusions below.

Answer (score 1):

Let me provide my own research findings for reference.

As Nico said, with the combination of `pvtu/vtu` files, we could theoretically implement a geometry structure stored in a separate `vtu` file, referenced by a `pvtu` file. Setting the NumberOfPieces attribute of the `ptvu` file to 1 would enable the construction of only one separate `vtu` file.

However, the VTK library does not expose a dedicated operation interface to control the writing process of `vtu` files. No matter how it is set, as long as the writer's input contains geometry structures, the writer will write geometry information to disk, and this process cannot be skipped through the exposed interface.

However, it is indeed possible to make multiple `pvtu` files point to the same `vtu` file by manually editing the piece node in the `ptvu` file, and paraview can recognize and visualize such a file group properly.

I did not proceed to try adding arrays to the unstructured grid and using `pvtu` output.

So, I think the conclusion is.

1. if you don't want to dive into VTK's library code and XML implementation, then this approach doesn't make sense.
2. if you are willing to write a series of files, delete most of them from the `vtu` file, and then point all the pvtu's piece nodes to the only surviving `vtu` file by editing the `pvtu` file, you can save a lot of disk space, but will not shorten the write, read, and parse times.
3. If you implement an XML writer by yourself, you can achieve all the requirements in theory, but it requires a lot of coding work.